# How to add a table from ArcGIS Online to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-online

When you're signed into ArcGIS Online within an ArcMap session, there is an option Add Data From ArcGIS Online:

[image]

I have a service in ArcGIS Online which consists of 2 feature layers and 1 table:

[image]

When I add this to ArcMap using the above option, the table isn't included. Is this a bug, or is there a workaround?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I am able to publish a service to AGOL with a table and when I add it to ArcMap from the My Hosted Services section, I can see both feature class and the table. They can come from the same gdb or different ones (tested only file gdb, not SDE). However, when I use the web site as you do, I get only feature classes, not the table. I guess the workaround would be to use ArcMap My Hosted Services when you need to add tables as well.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov can you clarify "when I add it to ArcMap from the My Hosted Services section" - I'm not sure how to do this? If you put this as an answer, it sounds like I'll be able to close this off. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to publish a service to AGOL with a table and when I add it to ArcMap from the [My Hosted Services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000044n000000) section (Catalog window in ArcMap > right-click My Hosted Services > Sign In), I can see both feature class and the table. They can come from the same gdb or different ones (I tested only file gdb, not SDE, but should work fine too).

However, when I use the web site as you do (go to ArcGIS.com and sign in > My Content > open service > View in ArcGIS Desktop), I get only feature classes, not the table. It might be a limitation of the ArcGIS.com. The workaround I am aware of is to use ArcMap's My Hosted Services when you need to add a service that has a table among other pieces of data.

Comment: thanks. sounds like a bug but the workaround is easy enough